# Scrolling background in PyGame with Entity Component System

Tags: tilemap, pygame, entity-component-system

I know this type of question has been asked to death for 'normal' games, however I am struggling with relating a scrolling background to an entity component system (ECS) approach.

Generic samples [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48554/pygame-2d-scrolling-map) and [here](https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/game-development-with-python/side-scroller-pygame/background/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319181/how-to-scroll-the-background-surface-in-pygame).

What I struggle with is how to take a fairly procedural view of this problem and abstract it out to an ECS.  I'm trying to get a roguelike game up and running in PyGame using [Esper](https://github.com/benmoran56/esper/).  I do have a proof of concept up and running where I generate a large map, however I'm having issues relating how to add a camera here as an entity that other objects would relate to.  I'm guessing that I need to refactor my movement code to be based around a camera, and have each separate entity update their relative position as a result.

At present, the background is being directly drawn and needs to be abstracted to an Entity in this system, but I was somewhat holding off on that until I figured out the camera.  Here is a snippet of the `Renderable` class that each drawn entity has:

```python
class Renderable:
    def __init__(self, image, posx, posy, depth=0):
        self.image = image
        self.depth = depth
        self.x = posx
        self.y = posy
 
        self.curr_row, self.curr_col = convert_to_cells(posx, posy)
 
        self.w = image.get_width()
        self.h = image.get_height()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h)
```

And here are the Movement processor and Render processors:

```python
class MovementProcessor(esper.Processor):
    def __init__(self, minx, maxx, miny, maxy, game_map):
        super().__init__()
        self.minx = minx
        self.maxx = maxx
        self.miny = miny
        self.maxy = maxy
        self.game_map = game_map
 
    def process(self):
        # This will iterate over every Entity that has BOTH of these components:
        for ent, (vel, rend) in self.world.get_components(Velocity, Renderable):
            # Check if movement is valid:
            newx = rend.x + int(vel.x * TILE_SIZE)
            newy = rend.y + int(vel.y * TILE_SIZE)
            new_row, new_col = convert_to_cells(newx, newy)
 
            if self.game_map.data[new_row][new_col] > 1:
              # Update the Renderable Component's position by it's Velocity:
              rend.x = newx
              rend.y = newy
              rend.curr_row = new_row
              rend.curr_col = new_col
 
class RenderProcessor(esper.Processor):
    def __init__(self, window, clear_color=(0, 0, 0)):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = window
        self.clear_color = clear_color
 
    def process(self):
        # Clear the window:
        self.window.fill(self.clear_color)
 
        # This will iterate over every Entity that has this Component, and blit it:
        for ent, rend in self.world.get_component(Renderable):
            self.window.blit(rend.image, (rend.x, rend.y))
 
        # Flip the framebuffers
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Later on in my main loop I iterate over my tilemap (`Map` class) and simply draw it to a surface, add some debugging overlays, and then assign that surface to the entity associated with the background (`bg_entity`):

```python
        # Blit background directly -- this needs to be abstracted out
        for row in range(len(game_map.data)):
          for col in range(len(game_map.data[0])):
            rect = pygame.Rect(col*TILE_SIZE,row*TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE)

            # Blit a wall sprite
            if game_map.data[row][col] in [0,1]:
              bg_surface.blit(walls[game_map.data[row][col]],rect)

            # Blit a floor/grass sprite
            elif game_map.data[row][col] in [2,3,4,5]:
              bg_surface.blit(floors[game_map.data[row][col]-2],rect)
```

Here is the full listing:

https://pastebin.com/N7c4TXXB

Comment: "have each separate entity update their relative position as a result" that sounds like a nightmare. Usually, each entity cares only about their position in world space, which is independent of any and all cameras. Then when rendering the view from one particular camera, you transform all those world coordinates by the camera's parameters to get the display-space coordinates.

Comment: Fair point and probably points to why I'm struggling.  As of now the `RenderProcessor` iterates over all entities and blits them.  Could this be as simple as tracking the current camera viewport and checking to see if each entity's `x` and `y` are within that view?

Comment: Try it and find out! The results of your own testing will tell you much more than the opinion of some Internet rando like me. 

Comment: As a quick check, I am seeing sprites not rendering when I add it in and scroll, so I think this is the way to go.  (Now to update the background and have the player 'stick' to the middle)